# How to adapt this code to saving?

Tags: jquery, hide, show, getjson, .post

```js
$('.working').hide();
$('.off-work').show();
$('.oversigt').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this);
    t.hide().siblings('.oversigt').show();
});
```

```css
  * {
      font-size:72px;
  }
.oversigt {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
.off-work {
    background:red;
}
.working {
    background:lime
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Havens Gartnere</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50%">Name</th>
        <th style="width:50%">Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>Hanne</td>
        <td id="hanne">
            <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
            <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>Lars</td>
        <td id="lars">
            <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
            <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jfunc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to save the state after click.
I have tried tutorials about mySQL and Jquery ajax but i dont understand how i can get my code to work with these features, i dont understand coding so well, can somebody please help me?

Comment: I have corrected a typo error in the title, highlighted inline code blocks (using backticks) and have removed fluff. Signatures, *thanks notes*, *I have this problem* kind of statements are considered as fluff and are not required to be present in the question.

Comment: Coming to the actual question, it is a bit unclear. What do you mean by save the `.hide` or `.show` function? Do you want to store the state or store the content? Please clarify more.

Comment: I want to store the state, and i dont know how. Should i use a mySQL or should i use .post .get in jquery and how can i do it?